# how mobx knows which variables component is binded to?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mobx, mobx-react

I know that MobX can detect when an object property changes (in our case `myData.name`), but how does MobX know the `User` component  **depends on** `myData.name`?

```js
class MyData {
    @observable name = "John"
}

@observer
class User extends Component {      
    render() {
        // here, User depends on myData.name, but how MobX know??
        let { name } = this.props.myData;
        return <div>{name}</div>
    }
}

let myData = new MyData();
ReactDOM.render(<User myData={myData} />, document.getElementById('root'));

// this triggers User component to refresh, but how does MobX know User
// component depends on MyData.user?
setTimeout(function(){
    myData.name = "Peter";
}, 2000)
```

Comment: At a high level, observer (or similar functions like [autorun](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html)) will register all the observables it accessed during render. When these observables change, the observer will re-run.

Answer (score 2):

The render() function of User is of special importance to mobx becuse you have decorated User as an observer (with @observer). As [mobx docs](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html) say....

"MobX reacts to any existing observable property that is **read** **during** the execution of a **tracked function**."

- "reading" is dereferencing an object's property, which can be done
  through "dotting into" it (eg. user.name) or using the bracket
  notation (eg. user['name']).
- "trackable functions" are the expression of computed, the render()
  method of an observer component, and the functions that are    passed
  as the first param to when, reaction and autorun.
- "during" means that only those observables that are being read while
  the function is executing are tracked. It doesn't matter    whether
  these values are used directly or indirectly by the tracked
  function.